# Terminating app due to uncaught exception due to uncaught exception (Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent) error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, swift

I'm trying to make a label which will be shown when the game launches, but it crashes as soon as it starts. The error is "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  name:'(null)' text:'TAP ANYWHERE TO START!' fontName:'Copperplate' position:{187.5, 333.5}'".This is my code:

```
let startGameTextNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Copperplate")

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(size: CGSize) {

    super.init(size: size)

 startGameTextNode.text = "TAP ANYWHERE TO START!"
        startGameTextNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Center
        startGameTextNode.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.Center
        startGameTextNode.fontSize = 20
        startGameTextNode.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        startGameTextNode.position = CGPoint(x: scene!.size.width / 2, y: scene!.size.height / 2)
        addChild(startGameTextNode)
```

I do have a background texture that moves too as soon as the game launches, and I'm not sure if that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I got it working. I was adding it too late on the scene. I just moved it up before it adds the ground to the scene and the app started working.